# Solr wildcards configuration issue

Tags: solr, wildcard, stemming

hi who can i configure solr to find everyting like an texteditor?

i have a field which contains

```
... text texct blah Computer-Zeitalter blah text m00h ...
```

i've configured it like this

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" 
                generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="1"
                catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"
                splitOnNumerics="0" stemEnglishPossessive="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />   
        <filter class="solr.EnglishPorterFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="100" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

but

```
select/?q=volltext:*eitalter&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on
select/?q=volltext:eitalter&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on
```

give no results, why?

i'm using solr 1.4

Comment: which version of Solr are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use `EnglishPorterFilterFactory`, it eliminates the *"er"* suffix from the *Zeitalter* and index it as *zeitalt*. So, if you want to find this keyword then

- you should either change your query as `...q=volltext:*eitalt&...`
- or you should remove `EnglishPorterFilterFactory` from the field definition and search using `...q=volltext:*eitalter&...`

Comment: hi thanks, i removed EnglishPorterFilterFactory and reindexed everything, but the query still returns 0 results, do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: sorry my fault, it solved the problem: i just queried the wrong server